# How to set Sublime Text 3 mouse event to trigger both custom behavior and default behavior?

Tags: plugins, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I would like to override double click in Sublime Text 3 to run my plugin code if and only if the user is in a certain view. Otherwise the double click should do the normal behavior (highlight the word and other instances in a file). However, I do not want the normal behavior to be run in my custom view.

The appropriate code for achieving this in Sublime Text 2 (and Python 2) can be found from https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8823 but I am not able to refactor it to work in Sublime Text 3 (and Python 3).

The working code (taken from the aforementioned link) for Sublime Text 2 is:

```
class MySpecialDoubleclickCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run_(self, args):
        if self.view.name() == "mySpecialBuffer":
            self.doMyStuff()
        else:
            system_command = args["command"] if "command" in args else None
            if system_command:
                system_args = dict({"event": args["event"]}.items() + args["args"].items())
                self.view.run_command(system_command, system_args)
```

In order to get it to work in Python 3 I refactored the dictionary handling code to (otherwise the code is the same):

```
system_args = dict({"event" : args["event"].items() | args["args"].items()})
```

However, when I call the `run_command(system_command, system_args)` method it returns the following error message:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime.py", line 607, in run_command
sublime_api.view_run_command(self.view_id, cmd, args)
TypeError: Value required
```

Since the API documentation for Sublime Text 3 is almost nonexistent I am trying to figure out is there some problem in my `system_args` dictionary or is the API just changed in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question is old, but better be late than sorry, stumble at it today

`ValueError` in my opinion is thrown by `sublime.decode_value(string)`

This method is decodes a JSON string into an object and as i think used in `run_command` then parsing args for running a command from keystroke or calling internaly.

The `.sublime-keymap` files contain a JSON array that contains JSON objects to specify the key bindings. The JSON objects must contain a `keys` and `command` key, and may also contain a `args` key if the command requires arguments.

So if arg value is not valid JSON object, you get `ValueError`

Workaround - pass strings or numbers

`view.run_command('name', {'string_arg': 'string', 'num_arg': 1})`

```
class NameCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit, string_arg, num_arg):
        pass
```

Or dump your object as JSON string pass to command and restore at place

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done any mouse binding stuff myself, but it appears you are missing an argument for the run command. Note it expects 3 parms, you only give to. Have you tried passing in `self.view.id` as the first parm (based on the error, that's probably what it's expecting).

Comment: If I change the command to have an id as a first parameter (i.e. `self.view.run_command(self.view.id, system_command, system_args)` I'll get the following error: `File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\MyPlugin\output.py", line 153, in run_
    self.view.run_command(self.view.id, system_command, system_args)
TypeError: run_command() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake, I misread the code. I thought you were calling `sublime_api.view_run_command` directly in some way. It appears you are trying to override the `run_` method, rather than the normal `run` method. I don't know that it'll fix anything, you should probably match the signature of the existing method which is `def run_(self, edit_token, args):`

Comment: Same error appears even if I match the signature of the existing method. I also tried to call directly `sublime_api.view_run_command(self.view_id, cmd, args)` but it gives me more mysterious error message: `TypeError: String required`.